# Updating array element in xml document

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

This code:

```
$test = @"
<Test>
  <Child>Hello</Child>
  <Child>World</Child>
</Test>
"@

$xml = [xml]$test
$xml.Test.Child[1]
```

yields:

```
World
```

Then this code:

```
$xml.Test.Child[1] = "StackOVerflow"
$xml.InnerXml
```

yields:

```
<Test><Child>Hello</Child><Child>World</Child></Test>
```

Why the second `Child` node is not getting updated from `World` to `StackOverflow`?

Okay, let's try something different:

```
$ipaddress=([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses($hostname)|Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork"}   |  select-object IPAddressToString)[0].IPAddressToString
```

Now I wonder what the type of `$ipaddress` is:

```
$ipaddress.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Apparently it's string.

```
$xml.Test.ChildNodes[1].'#text' = $ipaddress
Cannot set "#text" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.
At line:1 char:1
+ $xml.Test.ChildNodes[1].'#text' = $ipaddress
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XmlNodeSetShouldBeAString
```

But `$ipaddress` is string!

This finally works:

```
$xml.Test.ChildNodes[1].'#text' = [string]$ipaddress
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be related to a bug that might have been fixed in PowerShell 6. I don't have a Linux machine at hand to check.

You'll find a description of that bug [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2459).

Meanwhile, there is a workaround, as you have found it:

```
$test = @"
<Test>
  <Child>Hello</Child>
  <Child>World</Child>
</Test>
"@

$xml = [xml]$test
$xml.Test
$xml.Test.GetType()                 # = XmlElement

$xml.Test.Child[1]                      # = World
$xml.Test.Child[1].GetType()            # = String

$xml.Test.Child[1] = "Tralala"
$xml.Test.Child[1]                      # = World


$xml.Test.ChildNodes.Item(1).GetType()  # = XmlElement
$xml.Test.ChildNodes.Item(1)."#text" = "StackOverflow"
$xml.Test.Child[1]                      # = StackOverflow
```

Comment: Same behavior on PowerShell 6.0.0-alpha.13

Comment: Thank you for this, but as you might have noticed, I've posted the same work around in the original question itself.